# what format should be passed for material ui time picker?

Tags: reactjs, date, material-ui, time-format, date-fns

I'm trying to set a value for material-ui.
I've tried to pass a Date object, it denied it, with the following error:

```
 The format is "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm" followed by optional ":ss" or ":ss.SSS".
```

so I tried to copy it to date-fns:

```
const timeSelected = format(new Date(this.state.date),"yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm");
console.log(timeSelected);
let datePicker =<> <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}><TimePicker
    ampm={false}
    id="due-time"
    label="due time"
    type="datetime-local"

    value={timeSelected}
    InputLabelProps={{
        shrink: true,
    }}
    
    onChange={this.handleDateChange}
    disabled={!this.state.dateChangeable}
/>
</MuiPickersUtilsProvider></>;
```

and yet the error continues.
Can anyone spot the mistake?